# If $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such $|1-|2-|3-|4-\cdots-|2011-x|\cdots||||=x$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$, and such
$$|1-|2-|3-|4-\cdots-|2011-x|\cdots||||=x$$
find the maximum of the $x$

I have try $f(x)=|1-|2-|3-|4-\cdots-|2011-x|\cdots||||$,I have find
$$f(0)=0,f(1)=1,f(2)=0$$

Comment: Well, using Desmos, I have an idea that the maximum is at most $0,1.$

Comment: @JasonKim How did you write the formula to get it into Desmos?

Comment: Like $\left|1-\left(\left|2-\left(\left|3-\left(4-x\right)\right|\right)\right|\right)\right|$

Comment: @JasonKim I should have realized that.  I thought you had some magic way to enter the whole thing.

Comment: If a solution $x$ is larger than $1$, it must be giant. Indeed, if $x = |1-|2-|\ldots||| > 1$, then $|2-|\ldots|| > 2$. So, $|3-|\ldots|| > 4$ and hence $|4 - |\ldots|| > 7$ and so on.

Comment: That is, $x$ must be larger than $1+\frac 1 2\cdot 2011\cdot 2012$.

Comment: For $x=2023066=1+2+\cdots+2011$, the big expression evaluates to zero; for larger $x$ the graph has slope $1$ and therefore never crosses $y=x$.

Comment: @vadim123 How do you get to the conclusion that the slope is $1$?

Comment: @vadim123 Now I see why. Great, so the answer is $x = 1$.

Comment: Yup... it took me a long time to realize what to do.
Also, we need to prove that $x=1$ works if we are to claim that $x=1...$

Comment: @JasonKim I added this in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let us show that $x=1$ is the largest fixed point of $f(x) = |1-|2-|\ldots-|2011-x|\ldots|||$. First of all, it can be easily seen that it is indeed a fixed point (see the table below).

Now, let $N := 1+\ldots+2011$. We definitely have $f(N) = 0$ and $f(N+z) = z$ for $z\ge 0$. So, $f$ cannot have a fixed point larger than $N$.

Assume that $x > 1$ is a fixed point of $f$. Then $1 < x = |1-|2-|\ldots|||$. That means that the non-negative number $|2-|\ldots||$ has distance larger than $1$ to $1$. That is, $|2-|\ldots|| > 2$. Hence, similarly, $|3-|\ldots|| > 4 = 1 + 1 + 2$. Therefore, $|4-|\ldots|| > 7 = 1 + 1 + 2 + 3$ and so on. In the end, $|2011-x| > 1 + 1 +\ldots + 2010$. So $x > 1+N$, which is a contradiction.

Here is why $x=1$ is a fixed point of $f$:

$$
\begin{matrix}
k & |k-a|\\
2011 & \boxed{2010}\\
\boxed{2010} & 0 \\
2009 & 2009\\
2008 & 1\\
2007 & \boxed{2006}\\
\boxed{2006} & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots\\
 & \boxed{2}\\
\boxed{2} & 0\\
1 & 1
\end{matrix}
$$
The boxed values are the ones that are even but not divisible by $4$.

Comment: Why must $x$ be so large? I can't tell...

Comment: What is it you don't understand in my reasoning?

Comment: $N=1+2+3...+2011$

Comment: @JasonKim How do you think I can understand what you mean? Try to show a bit of empathy. That's also very important when writing proofs in mathematics. You don't write them to show others that you have understood the problem, but *for making others understand*. So, when you write something mathematic, think twice about whether other people can understand your stuff. What I have written above and what you stated in your last comment is the definition of a number, nothing more.

Comment: I don't understand why we need to prove for just all numbers $N$ greater than $1.$
Also, I suggest writing a few more terms to make the reader understand how it went from all $1$'s to $2011.$

Comment: @JasonKim "I don't understand why we need to prove for just all numbers N greater than 1" Prove what? That $x > 1$ cannot be a fixed point?

Answer (score 0):

We claim that $1$ is the highest value for which $f_{2011}(x)=x.$

Let $f_a(x)$ represent $|1-|2-|3-|4-...-|a-x|...||||.$

We look for a pattern to calculate $f_{2011}(1).$

Take note that for $c>4,$ we have $f_{c}(1)=f_{c-1}(|c-1|)=f_{c-1}(|c-1|)=f_{c-2}(|(c-1)-(c-1)|)=f_{c-2}(0)=f_{c-3}(|c-3|)=f_{c-3}(c-3)=f_{c-4}((c-4)-(c-3))=f_{c-4}(|-1|)=f_{c-4}(1).$
Applying this repeatedly gives $f_{2011}(1)=f_{2007}(1)=f_{2003}(1)=...=f_{3}(1)=|3-|2-|1-1|||=|3-|2-0||=|3-2|=1.$ Therefore, $f_{2011}(x)=x$ is satisfied for $x=1.$

Now we will prove that that is the maximum possible value of $x$ which can work.

We will evaluate $f_{2011}(2).$ We let $d$ be a positive integer such that $g<4.$ We will start to evaluate $f_{a}(2)$. Calculating, we have $f_{a}(2)=f_{a-1}(|a-2|)=f_{a-1}(a-2)=f_{a-2}(|(a-1)-(a-2)|)=f_{a-2}(1).$ Applying this, we get $f_{2011}(2)=f_{2009}(1)=f_{1}(1)=|1-1|=0.$

We know that the slope of the absolute value is $-1$ or $1$ since there is just one variable $x,$ and the absolute value would change its coefficient, and nothing else.

Since we know that the function is continuous, we have that from $f_{2011}(1)$ to $f_{2011}(2)$ that the slope is $-1.$ We know that from there, even if it it has a slope of $1$ $f_{2011}(2)$ to infinity, it would still be an parallel line that never intersects. That means for every real number greater than $2,$ since $y=x$ can't intersect with $f_{2011}(x),$ $x=1$ is the greatest solution $\boxed{\text{Q.E.D.}}.$